# Searching Custom Posts content with JQuery

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, search

I am adapting the site's archive pages for CPT's to use a masonry layout and adding a live search to the archive page. I have a setup that is working. However I've just realized that my script will only search the content that is displayed on the Archive page and not the content of the entire post. Please see my script below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#live-search").on("keyup", function(){
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#member-archive-left .member-archive-box").filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
            console.log($(this));
            $("#member-archive-left").masonry('layout');
        });
    });
});
```

This works exactly how I would like it to. I just need it to be able to search the content of the posts on the page. I'm, starting to think I'm going to need to rewrite it, but if anyone has a solution they think I should look at, please let me know!

Comment: We would need to see the other side of the code to help - some php? Unless the content is called into the DOM using `the_content()` on each post php side you won't be able to search for it using jQuery

Comment: Your question is not related to WordPress but rather to JQuery, you should seek information on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) instead.

Comment: @Aurovrata This is definitely about Wordpress. The jQuery works fine. However It does look like unless I use Ajax I'm not going to get the results I need. In the mean time I'm just calling `the content` in a hidden field and searching that way.

Comment: @Meds Ajax and JQuery are not specific to WP. I don't understand why you want to use Ajax?  Ajax is used to communicate with the server without reloading the entire page.  You want to search post content on the page using jquery for which you have to make sure the content you want to search is actually available on the page, else you can use Ajax to either load that content to search it or send your search query to the server and search the content on the server side, returning the matched results.

Comment: @Aurovrata WP has it's own hooks for Ajax. So therefore asking a WP forum for the best way to use it seems A'OK.
The reason I wanted to do it the way that I have been trying to, is because I am using masonry.js to give the affect of the posts rearranging as they get `displayed: none;`'d by the jQuery script I have written. I was asking if there was another way of searching the entire post without having to load it on the front end. I don't want the page to be reloaded because then the masonry rearranging won't fire. Seeing as you have nothing constructive or helpful why are you commenting?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're searching on the user end (as far as I can see), you will only be able to find data that has been sent to the user. So, if you archive page does not include the full post, you won't be able to search that.

The obvious solution is that you'll need to send all post content over. There are two possible approaches:

1. From within the script, retrieve the posts using the [rest-api](http://v2.wp-api.org/). This means you won't have to change the archive page as it is. It might affect performance, though, as you may be issuing a lot of data request to your server which may also be hold up during transfer to the user end
2. Change the archive page so it includes the complete posts and use some css to hide the full content as long as it is not needed. Probably the best approach.

Comment: Thanks! I did come to this realisation yesterday, I will look at your suggestions thank you!